# Can I change the order of watches in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, debugging

Often when I work with complex methods I have many watches active simultaneously. If I add a new watch it will be placed at the bottom of the list. Sometimes, though, I would like the new watch next to some other watch, because the two variables have some connection. I haven't found a way to do this, other than having to delete and reinsert watches. Is there a better way to do it?

Considering the long and mostly impressive history of the Delphi IDE, I feel the watches window has been neglected. As far as I recall it behaved identically in Turbo Pascal :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything from inside the IDE, but you can change the order in the Watches section of the dsk file.

Comment: It seems this was the closest I got :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can categorize watches into different groups, by double-clicking on them and specifying a group name.  This will place them in different tabs.

Comment: I'm aware of this, and it's a nice feature. But it's not enough :-)